Completely disable the Gtk+-3 WebKitWebView scroll bars
The WebKit2.WebView() widget is always scrollable, which is not ideal if it shall be embedded into another container (e.g. a box) which contains additonal items and shall be scrollable as a whole.  E.g. consider the following simple example:
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

win = Gtk.Window()
win.set_size_request(200, 100)
sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
sw.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS, Gtk.PolicyType.ALWAYS)
win.add(sw)
vp = Gtk.Viewport()
sw.add(vp)
box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
vp.add(box)
box.pack_start(Gtk.Label(label='some widget'), False, True, 0)
wv = WebKit2.WebView()
wv.load_uri('https://www.startpage.com')
box.pack_start(wv, True, True, 0)
box.pack_start(Gtk.Label(label='other widget'), False, True, 0)
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()

Is there a simple way to always disable the scroll bars of the WebKit2.WebView() widget, i.e. in this example, its height should be the full size of the displayed web site?
I played a little bit with catching the size-allocate signal of the WebKit2.WebView, reading the widget's natural height (by calling get_preferred_height()) and applying it by calling set_size_request(), but this doesn't work always, and seems to be very complex when the window is resized, or when the zoom factor of the WebKit2.WebView` is changed.
Does a simple (or simpler) solution exist for this task? Any insight would be highly appreciated!
